# How to convert html menu with dropdown to wordpress dynamic menu?

Tags: html, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I converting my html menu to WordPress dynamic menu. I am using wp_get_nav_menu_items() function but I am not able to retrieve dropdown menus properly. Here is my html structure for menu.

```
<li><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown nav-item active">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home One</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Company <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Features <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Parent Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#!">Child Menu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have used wp_get_nav_menu_items as follows.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark p-0">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <?php
            $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations(); 
            $menuID = $menuLocations['header'];
            $menu   = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuID);
            ?>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <?php
            foreach ( $menu as $navItem ) {
            $subMenu = wp_get_nav_menu_items($navItem->ID);
            $hasSubMenu = $subMenu;
            $dropdownArrow = $hasSubMenu ? '<span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>' : '';

            echo '<li class="nav-item' . ( $hasSubMenu ? ' dropdown' : '' ) . '"><a class="nav-link' . ( $hasSubMenu ? ' dropdown-toggle' : '' ) . '" href="'.$navItem->url.'" title="'.$navItem->title.'" ' . ( $hasSubMenu ? 'data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"' : '' ) . '>'.$navItem->title . $dropdownArrow . '</a>';

            if ( $hasSubMenu ) {
                echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">';
                foreach ( $subMenu as $subMenuItem ) {
                echo '<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="' . $subMenuItem->url . '">' . $subMenuItem->title . '</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }

            echo '</li>';
            }
        ?>
       </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

How can I create dynamic menu that follows classes like html menu. Please give me your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling all the day, I have found the solution.

Add this function in your functions.php.

```
function wp_get_menu_array($current_menu) {
    $menu_name = $current_menu;
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menuObj = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
    $array_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menuObj->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
    $menu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if (empty($m->menu_item_parent)) {
            $menu[$m->ID] = array();
            $menu[$m->ID]['ID']          =   $m->ID;
            $menu[$m->ID]['title']       =   $m->title;
            $menu[$m->ID]['url']         =   $m->url;
            $menu[$m->ID]['children']    =   array();
        }
    }
    $submenu = array();
    foreach ($array_menu as $m) {
        if ($m->menu_item_parent) {
            $submenu[$m->ID] = array();
            $submenu[$m->ID]['ID']       =   $m->ID;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['title']    =   $m->title;
            $submenu[$m->ID]['url']      =   $m->url;
            $menu[$m->menu_item_parent]['children'][$m->ID] = $submenu[$m->ID];
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}

?>
```

Call this function in your header like this.

```
<?php $menu_items = wp_get_menu_array('header'); ?>
<div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <?php foreach ($menu_items as $item) : ?>
            <?php if( !empty($item['children']) ){ ?>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="<?= $item['url'] ?>" title="<?= $item['title'] ?>" data-toggle="dropdown"><?= $item['title'] ?> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </a>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?= $item['url'] ?>" title="<?= $item['title'] ?>"><?= $item['title'] ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if( !empty($item['children']) ):?>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <?php foreach($item['children'] as $child): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?= $child['url'] ?>" title="<?= $child['title'] ?>"><?= $child['title'] ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <ul>
</div>
```

You can add classes according to your requirements.